# Appcrash on running UmfPackLU<> with Eigen library

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen, umfpack

I am compiling and trying to run the `UMfPackLU<SparseMatrix<>>` routine from `Eigen 3.2.9` and `UMFPACK v4.5` libraries with `TDM-GCC 5.1.0` on `Win64` platform. But I am getting `Appcrash` with `exception code c0000005`.

What I need to implement is the following:

```
     _ _        _ _
A = | P |, B = | R |, where P and Q are sparse and Z is 0 with 3 cols
    | Q |      | Z |
    |_ _|      |_ _|

X = A\B;
```

What I am doing (excerpt only) is the following:

```
#define num_t double
...
SparseMatrix<num_t,RowMajor> A(P.rows()+Q.rows(), P.cols());
A.topRows(P.rows()) = P;
A.bottomRows(Q.rows()) = Q;
Matrix<num_t, Dynamic, 3> B(P.rows()+Q.rows(), 3);
B.topLeftCorner(P.rows(), 3) = R;
B.bottomLeftCorner(Q.rows(), 3) = S;

UmfPackLU<SparseMatrix<num_t>> solver(A.transpose()*A);
auto AtB = A.transpose()*B;
X.col(0) = solver.solve(AtB.col(0)); // @@@ segmentation error here @@@
X.col(1) = solver.solve(AtB.col(1));
X.col(2) = solver.solve(AtB.col(2));
```

Note the `SparseMatrix<>` is in `RowMajor` format.

On debugging with `gdb`: I get `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.` at the line marked as above`.

Instead of `UmfPackLU<SparseMatrix<>>`, solving with `SimplicialLLT<SparseMatrix<>>`, `SimplicialLDLT<SparseMatrix<>>` or `CholmodDecomposition<SparseMatrix<>>` is working correctly.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You could try to update to Eigen v3.2.9 first

Comment: @kangshiyin: Updated to 3.2.9. Still the same error.

Comment: Win64 may be an issue. How about LP64?

Comment: @kangshiyin: Right now I don't have any `LP64` environment. However, the error seems to come from the `i` variable which gets a high negative value in the lines:
        i = Ai [p] ; // here `i` gets a negative value
 /* axx = Ax [p] * xj ; */
 ASSIGN (aij, Ax, Az, p, AXsplit) ;
 MULT (axx, aij, xj) ;
 /* W [i] -= axx ; */
 DECREMENT (W [i], axx) ;

in the function `UMF_solve()` in `umf_solve.c` of the `umfpack` library.

Comment: @kangshiyin: Also, I have a very little understanding of `LP64`. Could you explain me what you are asking me to do with that?

Comment: You could google "win64 lp64 lllp64 ilp64". You could test umfpack without Eigen to see whose fault this is.

Comment: First of all, check that `solver.info()==Success` before trying to call `solve`. If this test is OK, then try to declare `AtB` as a `Matrix<num_t, Dynamic, 3>`  instead of an expression and directly call `X = solver.solve(AtB)`.

Comment: @ggael: when i am doing `auto X2 = solver.solve(AtB);`, it runs without a error. But the error comes when I am assigning `X = solver.solve(AtB);` with `X` declared as `Matrix<num_t, Dynamic, 3> X`.The sizes are same. Could you suggest me a way to check the type of the output matrix `X2`. Note the same thing works for other solvers. BTW, `solver.info()==Success ` returns `true`.

Comment: btw, since you are factorizing a SPD matrix, Cholmod is probably a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

This is a shortcoming in Eigen 3.2.9 that has been fixed a while ago in the 3.3 branch. It's now fixed in the 3.2 branch too (changeset 1e7d97fea51d).

You can workaround the issue by calling `compute(...)` instead of the constructor:

```
UmfPackLU<SparseMatrix<num_t>> solver;
solver.compute(A.transpose()*A);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please feel free to correct/enhance/establish my answer.**

What I have found is that, I need to instantiate an explicit `ColMajor` matrix `AtA` before feeding it to the solver (`RowMajor` is not working) as follows:

```
SparseMatrix<num_t, ColMajor> AtA = A.transpose()*A;
UmfPackLU<SparseMatrix<num_t>> solver(AtA);
```

Is this a requirement due to `Eigen`'s `lazy evaluation` implementation for calling an `external routine`?